# Python dictionary: pass multiple lists into dictionary as values

Tags: python, dictionary

Apologize for what might seem like an easy one.  I'm trying to take two python lists and assign them as values for a dictionary, with the keys defined to match the list characteristics.  For example, a list with only upper case words would be values for a key called "upperCase" and a list with lower case words would map as values to another key in the same dictionary called "lowerCase".  The lists I've already created by iterating over a string value, splitting them into a main list and then assigning them to new lists (if the index[0] position of the word is uppercase or lowercase.  My lists are such:

```
combDict = {}
isUpCase = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "John", "Jack"]
islowerCase = ["my", "name", "is", "human"]
```

My key assignments are "Upper" and "Lower"

My goal is to make my dictionary as so:

```
combDict = {Upper:  Hello, Upper:  Goodbye, Upper:  John, Upper:  Jack, Lower:  my, 
Lower:  name, Lower:  is, Lower:  human}
```

I've tried a couple of dictionary comprehensions but I cannot seem to get it right.  Thoughts?  What direction should I go?

Comment: You can't have multiple keys that map to different values. Would a list of upper/lowercased words be okay instead?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries do not take duplicate keys, therefore your goal dictionary is not possible. One solution would be to make combDict as a dictionary with lists as values.

```
combDict[Upper] = isUpCase
combDict[Lower] = islowerCase
```

If you are using the dictionary to figure out is a word is upper or lower case, you could set the word as key and its state (upper or lower case) as value, see below

```
for el in isUpCase:
   combDict[el] = Upper
for el in islowerCase:
   combDict[el] = Lower
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, Dictionary keys must be unique, meaning you can't have two keys with the same value.
I am interested to know what you want to achieve with that dictionary so that we can propose better solutions to you.

Comment: The dictionary construct is part of a pipeline. 1st phase:  Build a function that takes a string and assign them to one of two keys in a dictionary construct (for eventual vectorization).  The DictVectorizer (sklearn) will pull the features out of the dictionary construct.  The two features that I am wanting to extract are "Upper" and "Lower" such that the output eventually will be "Upper=<either 1 or zero, if word starst with upper> and "Lower=my, Lower=name, Lower=is, Lower=human".  So I am stuck at the point of creating that initial dictionary for the vectorizer to work.  Thoughts?

Comment: Like @HadiHammoud2000 pointed out, switching keys with values such that Lower & Upper are dict values and name, human... are keys can work out for you just fine, as long as this latter one is unique.